# Do motorbikes in Vietnam have room to carry a large backpacking backpack?

Tags: luggage, vietnam, motorcycles

If you buy/rent a motorbike in Vietnam do they have ones with the abilities to strap on a large backpacking backpack?

I've seen just regular motorbikes without any attachments for carrying luggage, but I'm assuming if two people can ride a bike then there's no reason a single person couldn't travel with a bag right?

Comment: Can you give an indication of a model? Motorcycles vary dramatically in size, length, weight and placement of items.  On some, you just add panniers (carrier bags), while on others it may be more difficult.

Comment: Not Vietnam, but it's a motorcycle: http://blogs.timeslive.co.za/minor/files/2009/11/cow.JPG

Comment: @MarkMayo I guess I'm looking for 'which motorbikes' would allow such a thing. I don't have a motorbike already (specific model) to ask about, I want to know if such a thing is possible and if so how. Thank you.

Comment: @Bart very awesome

Comment: Your question is worded in a way to yield no usable answer. There is offcourse at least a single motorbike in vietnam to rent or buy which has the ability to transport a large backpack. Further as you suggested if you keep your backpack on, on a bike made to transport 2 people you will be able to transport you and a backpack. have a look here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask to improve your question

Comment: The first time I went to Vietnam back when there was little infrastructure for backpackers the locals with motorbikes and scooters were a common form of public transport. On scooters the driver would perch your backpack on the small "floor" area between the seat and the handlebars. On motorbikes I have ridden as a pillion passenger with my backpack on but when your backpack is heavy this doesn't feel very safe or comfortable.

Comment: In [this linked photo](http://www.freedomcyclelasvegas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Overloaded-Luggage-300x225.jpg) ignore the craziness at the back of the bike but notice where the single suitcase is at the front. This is the only photo I've been able to find for what I'm talking about.

Comment: Look for 'vietnam moto' in google images and you will see that huge loads can be carried on a motorbike, or even a bicycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you buy/rent a motorbike in Vietnam do they have ones with the
>   abilities to strap on a large backpacking backpack?

A lot of South Asian countries have a collection of powerful pre/post war bikes which carried on production locally after the wars ended. Those were very accomadating bikes. For ex, does this (googled) bike's setup offer you enough storage space ?  http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/icarus2607/Sikkim%202007/Picture032.jpg

If that wasn't enough, you can also opt for a motorcyle with a side car : http://databikes.com/imgs/a/d/b/r/x/royal_enfield__bullet_350_team_1986_2_lgw.jpg

Such bike mods are pretty common in many South East Asian countries (Pakistan, India, Nepal, Bangladesh, Thailand, Burma etc). Unlike in US, many people over there travel luggage heavy on motorcycles and finding such a bike for rent shouldn't be a problem in a tourist place.

> I've seen just regular motorbikes without any attachments for carrying
>   luggage, but I'm assuming if two people can ride a bike then there's
>   no reason a single person couldn't travel with a bag right?

Oh yes, there should be no problem at all, from my experience in Asian countries so far. For *specific* local laws you will have to look up their motorcycle law manual. But as a general observation, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Pakistan, India, Nepal, and Bangladesh are not considered Southeast Asia but South Asia.

Comment: Very well, I stand corrected then South Asia it is.

Comment: Link to first image died. Anyway, those bike mods are extremely rare in Vietnam. It has been years since I last seen one on the road.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a luggage rack made easily for between $10 and $30 `USD`, depending on size. Some photos below show you how such a rack might look:

- http://www.offroadvietnam.com/Images/motorbikes/gl160luggagerackfull.jpg
- http://www.offroadvietnam.com/Images/motorbikes/waveluggagerack.jpg